# WPF + Controls.UserControl. How to find a control inside?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

In my WPF project, I have a System.Windows.Controls.UserControl control. How to find a control inside that contol ?

Comment: Care to give a concrete piece of code to help with? There are many different ways of resolving children depending on whether you want to do it in XAML or code.

Comment: I want to do it on the server side code

Answer (score 1):

use VisualTree, if I understood  your question correctly.

refer to msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409789.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In that case you would probably want to walk the visual tree, like this extension method does:

```
internal static T FindVisualChild<T>(this DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (parent == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    DependencyObject parentObject = parent;
    int childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject childObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentObject, i);
        if (childObject == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var child = childObject as T;
        return child ?? FindVisualChild<T>(childObject);
    }

    return null;
}
```

It requires that you know the type of the control you are looking for.